# Deserializing a JSON into a C# List of Objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, google-places-api

I am trying to Deserialize a JSON from google places api. My custom class is set up as follows and my code looks like this. My Program throws no errors when running but my places object is null.

```
class PlacesDictionary
{

    public void placesDictionary()
    { }

    public Places GetPlaces()
    {
        Places places = new Places();

        string apiKey = "I have an apiKey";
        string googleUrl;
        googleUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=43.038902,-87.906474&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=" + apiKey;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(googleUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(responseFromServer);

        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        Console.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return places;
    }
}

public class Places
{
    public List<Place> places { get; set; }

    public class Place
    {
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public int price_level { get; set; }
        public double rating { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
        public string vicinity { get; set; }

        public class Location
        {
            public double lat { get; set; }
            public double lng { get; set; }
        }

        public class Northeast
        {
            public double lat { get; set; }
            public double lng { get; set; }
        }

        public class Southwest
        {
            public double lat { get; set; }
            public double lng { get; set; }
        }

        public class Viewport
        {
            public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
            public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
        }

        public class Geometry
        {
            public Location location { get; set; }
            public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
        }

        public class OpeningHours
        {
            public bool open_now { get; set; }
            public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Photo
        {
            public int height { get; set; }
            public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
            public string photo_reference { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Restaurant object?

Comment: Sorry Places will hold the restaurants

Comment: If you don't add the JSON to the question any answer will be just a guess.

Comment: I have edited my answer and I have just tried and it works.

Comment: Awesome, was it because I didnt have a variables for the full results the status, next page token, and html_attributions

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
List<Place> places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Place>>(responseFromServer);
```

instead of

```
places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(responseFromServer);
```

and don't forget remove following line

```
 Places places = new Places();
```

**Edit: Full Answer**

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
           string apiKey = "your api key";
           string googleUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=43.038902,-87.906474&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=" + apiKey;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(googleUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("json.txt");
            //wr.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            //wr.Flush();
            //To see what it is inside json
            Result results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(responseFromServer);

            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            Console.ReadLine();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<HTMLAttribution> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string next_page_token { get; set; }
        public List<Place> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        //Definations of Classes
        public class HTMLAttribution { } //I don't what it is. It is empty for your url.

        public class Place
        {
            public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
            public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
            public string place_id { get; set; }
            public int price_level { get; set; }
            public double rating { get; set; }
            public string reference { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public List<string> types { get; set; }
            public string vicinity { get; set; }

            public class Geometry
            {
                public Location location { get; set; }
                public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
            }
            public class Location
            {
                public double lat { get; set; }
                public double lng { get; set; }
            }
            public class Viewport
            {
                public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
                public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
            }
            public class Northeast
            {
                public double lat { get; set; }
                public double lng { get; set; }
            }

            public class Southwest
            {
                public double lat { get; set; }
                public double lng { get; set; }
            }
            public class OpeningHours
            {
                public bool open_now { get; set; }
                public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
            }
            public class Photo
            {
                public int height { get; set; }
                public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
                public string photo_reference { get; set; }
                public int width { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to change my Class setup then as places is already a list?

Comment: Don't change Place class only remove Places class.

Comment: Honestly the entire Class Places Is not needed, nor the list property places.  All you need is the Place Class.

Comment: This removes the error that the first suggestion created and it creates an object I can see when debugging, but doesn't create a list of objects and all the object properties are null.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something (if I were you) :

delete 
`Places places = new Places();`

replace 
`places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);`
by
`Places places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);`

and add a default constructor in your class Places like you have add in PlacesDictionary.

Comment: Yes, Sorry places will hold restaurants when this works

Answer (score 0):

1.Just have Place class only.

2.Initialize `List<Place> places=new List<Place>()`

3.Deserialize using places

```
places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<places>(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: i have a places class which is a public List<Place> places { get; set; }.  Your saying I can remove that and just serialize to a list<Place> instead of having that be its own class?

Comment: places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(responseFromServer); If Places is no longer a class it cant be used as a type

Comment: Sorry my bad changed answer to the instance of list "places" while deserializing, yes Places will no longer be a class